# What is the solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the differential equation:

$$ y'=\frac{1}{2} \frac{2x + 3y^2+1}{3x+4y^2+1} $$

I thought it was a homogeneous differential equation and I tried to find the integrating factor and then substitute:

$$ u= \frac{y}{x} $$

However I don't think that is possible. I also tried to substitute:

$$ u = y^2$$
But I didn't get any results. I have just started learning differential equations so I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: It's certainly not homogeneous. Why do you think this has a closed-form solution? Maple and Wolfram Alpha don't find any.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I thought that after some substitution it would become a homogeneous equation. 
I tried maple too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y'=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2x+3y^2+1}{3x+4y^2+1}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2x+3y^2+1}{3x+4y^2+1}$

$(2x+3y^2+1)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=6x+8y^2+2$

$\left(x+\dfrac{3y^2+1}{2}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=3x+4y^2+1$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=x+\dfrac{3y^2+1}{2}$ ,

Then $x=u-\dfrac{3y^2+1}{2}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}-3y$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}-3y\right)=3\left(u-\dfrac{3y^2+1}{2}\right)+4y^2+1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}-3yu=3u-\dfrac{9y^2+3}{2}+4y^2+1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=3(y+1)u-\dfrac{y^2+1}{2}$

Let $s=y+1$ ,

Then $u\dfrac{du}{ds}=3su-\dfrac{(s-1)^2+1}{2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{ds}=3su-\dfrac{s^2}{2}+s-1$

Let $t=\dfrac{3s^2}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{ds}=3s\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore 3su\dfrac{du}{dt}=3su-\dfrac{s^2}{2}+s-1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u-\dfrac{s}{6}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3s}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u\mp\dfrac{\sqrt t}{3\sqrt 6}+\dfrac{1}{3}\mp\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 6\sqrt t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.